# How to trim a URI in CI3

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, codeigniter-3

How do you trim URL from:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

for example, code above is returning `/vobot-cms/perdana/Perdana/tambahData`.

How to trim that URL to only return `/Perdana`?

Comment: Make a habit of reading the framework docs always.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`uri->segment()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html)

```
$url = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Ex:

[image]

> **Note:** you have two `Perdana` in your URL. Add the number which you need